# Token definition with variables

Tags: antlr

I'm writing a grammar to parse a log file which looks like this:

```
V9013_MURGIN_AE_7340057[01/10/2013 10:07:33]:DEBUG:<PCDATA>
V9013_MURGIN_AE_7340057[01/10/2013 10:07:33]:DEBUG:<PCDATA>
etc...
```

where `PCDATA` can contain any symbol (incl. `\n`) and '7340057' is a PID (process id).

The question is, how to describe the end of `PCDATA`?

I can't say go nonreedy and match anything until you see a `V9013_MURGIN_AE_7340057`, because that is PID and it changes across log files, so I can't hardcode its value into grammar.

Is there a way to do something like this:

1. The first time I match a `7340057` (or whatever it is in the current
   file), put it into some var, say `$PID`
2. Describe `PCDATA` as nongreedy `(.)*`-match until `$PID` That is, is it possible to have a variable (parametrized) token definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest you do not use `antlr` for such things. It will be more easily implement such parser using simple constructions of any programming language (Java, C++, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion to not use ANTLR.

Yet, the way I've dealt with this problem (quite inneficiently) before is this:

```
pcdata : (PID)=> () | . pcdata ;
```